# Upload a javascript generated PDF file to server

Tags: javascript, jquery, pdf, coldfusion, pdfmake

Please note I am uploading a file generated at runtime, NOT a user submitted file. This is where my problem lies, taking that file and sending it along has proven itself to be truly a challenge.

I'm using PDFMake to generate a pdf file. It took me A LONG time to get this code working, tl;dr of it is I convert the pdf doc info to a buffer, make a new File object with that buffer, attach that file object to a formdata object, and send it to my server.

Here is the code:

```
    var pdfGen = pdfMake.createPdf(docDef);

    pdfGen.getBuffer(function(buffer){
        var pdf = new File(buffer, "testpdf.pdf", {type: "application/pdf"});
        var data = new FormData();
        data.append('upload', pdf);
        data.append('content-type', 'application/pdf');

        $.ajax({
            method: "POST",
            url: "/index.cfm?action=admin:service.upload_pdf",
            data: data,
            processData: false,
            contentType: false,
            success: function(msg){
                console.log(msg);
            },
            error: function(msg){
                console.log(msg);
            }
        })
    })
```

The problem is that the file I get on my server isn't a valid PDF. The application type is listed as application/octet-stream. The function I'm pushing the File object to *SHOULD* be rejecting everything except pdf's, so I'm not sure where the error is exactly.

I've been at this for two days now and I'm at a loss so any help is GREATLY appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried converting your generated PDF into Base64 and then sending the result to your server?
Here's what I mean:

```
var pdfGen = pdfMake.createPdf(docDef);
pdfGen.getBase64((data) => {
    PostToServer(data);
});
```

Source: https://github.com/bpampuch/pdfmake

Comment: My problem with this is coldfusion will not except a Base64 string as a file (I'm using the FileUpload function). I have tried a dataURL as well as just the Base64 and coldfusion won't let me pass it through. Thanks for the thought though!

Comment: Uhm, what if you don't use FileUpload? I mean: send the Base64-encoded PDF to your server through method POST as if it was a normal string. Then, use ColdFusion to retrieve that string, convert it to binary, and then writing it to a file.

Comment: Shit that is clever, I didn't think of it at all!  I actually solved it already using a different method but that is honestly brilliant mate

Comment: Base64 is very useful in these cases. How did you solve this problem anyway?

Comment: Well I took your suggestion and decided to use Base64 to construct the file instead of using the provided buffer. It was a bit of work but I found another great answer detailing how to convert Base64 to a byte array so that the file constructor would read it. After that the uploaded file contained the appropriate information!